# read line until ESC button in pressed in haskell

Tags: haskell, line, stdin

I need to real lines until ESC button is pressed. How can I check it?

```
lines
   = do
      line <- getLine
      if (== "/ESC") --this condition is wrong
         then ...
         else do
            ln <- lines
            return ...
```

Could anybody fix my problem?

Comment: Do you *need* to do it that way? It would be easier to implement a sentinel string, for example "quit". Then you merely write `if (line == "quit") then ... else ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to escape is with a backslash, the character is `'\ESC'`, so the condition would be

```
if line == "\ESC"
```

But I'm not sure every terminal passes an `'\ESC'` through to the application.

If you want to stop immediately when the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key is pressed, something along the lines of

```
module Main (main) where

import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
    getUntilEsc ""

getUntilEsc :: String -> IO ()
getUntilEsc acc = do
    c <- getChar
    case c of
      '\ESC' -> return ()
      '\n' -> do putStrLn $ "You entered " ++ reverse acc
                 getUntilEsc ""
      _ -> getUntilEsc (c:acc)
```

is what you need. You have to read character-wise, and you need to turn off the buffering of `stdin`, so the characters are immediately available for reading, and not only after a newline has been entered.

Note that on Windows turning off buffering didn't work. I don't know if this has been fixed recently.
Also, as @Daniel Wagner reported, it may well be that the Windows command prompt doesn't pass the <kbd>ESC</kbd> to the application.

Comment: mmm... it checks if input is equals to "\ECS". But it not checks if button is pressed. Or I am wrong?

Comment: It checks whether the line it got is `"\ESC"`, so it needs the return or enter key pressed. If you want to act immediately when `\ESC` is pressed, you need to read single characters, that means using `getChar` instead of `getLine` and turning off buffering for `stdin` - the latter used to not work on Windows, I don't know if it now does.

Comment: I think other people have told me in the past that Windows' command prompt doesn't send the escape key through, so that may be part of the problem as well.